# Barcode128 error - "Either there are no methods with the specified method name and argument types"

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have this script to generate a barcode in ColdFusion:

```
<cfscript>
   code128 = createobject("java","com.lowagie.text.pdf.Barcode128");
   code128.setCodeType(code128.CODE128);
   /* Set the code to generate */
   code128.setCode("123")
   color =  createobject("java","java.awt.Color");
   image = code128.createAwtImage(color.black, color.white);
   bufferedImage = createObject("java", "java.awt.image.BufferedImage");
   bufferedImageType = bufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
   bufferedImage = bufferedImage.init(image.getWidth(JavaCast("null", "")),image.getHeight(JavaCast("null", "")), bufferedImageType);
   graphics2D = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
   graphics2D.drawImage(image,0,0,JavaCast("null", ""));
   barcodeImage = imageNew(bufferedImage);
</cfscript>

<!--- Output the code as an image --->
<cfimage action="writeToBrowser" source="#barcodeImage#" format="jpg" width="100" height="30">
```

I want to change `code128.setCode("123")` to something dynamic, ie `code128.setCode("#someID#")`. However, when I do that I receive a CF error:

> Error message: Either there are no methods with the specified method
>   name and argument types or the setCode method is overloaded with
>   argument types that ColdFusion cannot decipher reliably. ColdFusion
>   found 0 methods that match the provided arguments. If this is a Java
>   object and you verified that the method exists, use the javacast
>   function to reduce ambiguity.

Can someone help me with this one?

Comment: Are you saying the code *does* work with `code128.setCode("123");` but does *not* work with `code128.setCode("#someID#");`? What is the value of #someID#? **That error usually means exactly what it says** - either a) you are trying to use a method that does not exist in the class at all OR b) you are passing in the wrong type of value, and need to use `javacast` to convert it. For example, if that method expects a string `code128.setCode( javacast("string", someID) );`. Side note, not sure if it a typo, but you are missing a semi-colon on line three.

Answer (score 6):

Try passing the value like this

```
code128.setCode(JavaCast("string", someID));
```

Comment: Javacast is usually the answer. when you pass something else it may be referenced as a number  - giving you the arg/method mismatch error.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the comments and above, javacast will probably do the trick.  When I tested it with `val(123)` the call failed. A little surprising it is needed, given that `setCode()` expects a string and is not overloaded, but ... {shrug}. Like the error message says, javacast cures most typing ills ;-)